# SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: sqlite, android

Здравствуйте!  
На некоторых девайсах(SGS 4 и HTC One)  падает ошибка

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MY_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: select * from MY_TABLE
```

Таблица в БД точно есть. 
База данных сливает с сервера, после скачивания проверяется md5 сумма, и только если она совпала с тем, что выдал сервер, только тогда производится обращение к БД. 
База данных хранится в стандартной дирректории **/data/data/mypackagename/databases**

Сталкивался ли кто-то с таки и как быть?

Comment: @Andreich версия Android'а какая?

Comment: @Barmaley Android 4.2(SGS 4)

Comment: Странно. В Киткат есть ограничения на доступ к БД и то если она расположена в карте памяти. В 4.2 должно все работать. А врукопашную подцепиться к БД и сделать запрос из консоли не пробовали?

Comment: @Barmaley у меня нет доступа к устройству. Ошибки сыпятся в отчетах. 
Что касается базы, то она вполне себе хорошо работает на других over 50к устройствах

Comment: Описал свою ошибку здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/54931870/7041761

Answer (score 1):

После расчета md5, я бы выполнил запрос

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

он покажет список таблиц и их структуру. Такая запись в логе сильно поможет.

Что может быть:

- недостаточно места в памяти. База скачалась, но не распаковалась корректно. Поэтому md5 проверка проходит, а запросы не выполняются.
- ошибка в алгоритме распаковки.
- на указанных девайсах возможно немного другая версия sqlite (это гипотеза) и их драйвер не может полноценно открыть базу.